# Problem creating a login authentication using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to create an AJAX script that calls a PHP script to check the entered username and password. The PHP script simply returns "true" if the entered details are correct and false if otherwise.

At the end of the AJAX script, I've placed a simple if else condition for true/false returns. Every time the PHP script returns true, the AJAX scripts jumps to else part overlooking the if.

I know there might be some stupid mistake or it is probably a ludicrous question but I'm stuck on it since many days. Stack is the last resort!

> Here's my AJAX SCRIPT

```
function authenticate() 
{
//XMLHttpRequest Object 

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
var pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;

var url = "php/user_authentication.php";
var url2 = "php/user_authentication.php?email=" + email + "&pass=" + pass;
var result = "";

xhttp.open("GET", url2, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send();


xhttp.onreadystatechange = function f() 
//f() would be called everytime the onreadystatechange property changes the value
    {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 

        {
            alert(this.responseText);
            result = this.responseText;

            if (result == "true") 
            //!! -> NOT ENTERING THIS PART EVEN WHEN result="true" !!
            {
                alert("Inside true");
                document.getElementById('email_pass').innerHTML = 'login successful';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('email_pass').innerHTML = 'login failed';
                alert("2 " + xhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

> Here's the PHP script [user_authentication.php]

```
<?php
//User Authentication

//1.Including the database_connection.php
include "database_connection.php";

//2.1.Fetching the user id and password from the form
$email = $_GET['email'];
$pass = $_GET['pass'];

//2.2.Defining th select query 
$qry = 'select * from user_auth where Email="'.$email.'" and Password = "'.$pass.'"';

//3.Executing the query and storing it to result
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$qry);

//authenticating
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    echo "true";

}
else
{
    echo "false";

}
?>
```

Comment: What does your alert say exactly ?

Comment: @giuseppedeponte It says true or false depending on what the PHP script returns

Comment: And what does it says if you try to print `result` instead of `this.responseText` ?

Comment: @giuseppedeponte When I do that, it says the same thing. true/false

Comment: What does it says if you print `typeof result` or `result.length` ?

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that.

Comment: In your PHP code, make sure you don't have any output (space, new line etc) before you open the PHP-block and also remove the closing `?>` from the end of the PHP file to make sure there won't be any output after it either.

Comment: I would also recommend that you use POST instead of GET when you make this request. Otherwise, the username/password will be stored in the browser history in plain text, which is pretty bad.

Comment: @giuseppedeponte Holy cow, the typeof result is string BUT when I checked result.length, it's showing 11 !! How is that even possible ?

Comment: _**Never ever** ever never_ store passwords in plain text! You should _always_ hash the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and only store the hashes. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: I think you have spaces in your response text. If you trim your result you should be fine: `result.trim()`

Comment: @giuseppedeponte Yes I used result.slice(0,1) and it worked perfectly. However, I still don't understand what are the spaces meant for. Any idea @giuseppedeponte?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you so much for providing so many critical points ! I'll make sure to fix them all. But I still don't get why use a hash table ? How is it better

Comment: @MagnusEriksson And also if you could shed light on why are there empty spaces coming along my responseText ? From where are they coming up?

Comment: _"I still don't get why use a hash table"_ - I haven't mentioned hash tables at all. What you should do is to hash the passwords. If you don't, anyone that would get  access to the database (you, developers, hackers) can see your users credentials in plain text, which is very bad. If you hash it before you store it, you will only have a hash of the password in the database. And using `password_hash()` will give you a secure and strong hash.

Comment: I think it must be the echo function that add extra space around your string.

Comment: Turns out (I asked my PHP collegue Benoit) that putting the closing PHP tag `?>` adds extra space to the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, 
I was getting some extra spaces along with my responseText that made the following condition false every time I got "true" in my responseText.

```
if (result == "true") 
//Turns false because result.length = 11 (extra empty spaces due to some unknown reasons)
```

> The solution was as follows :

1. Changing the return value in my PHP to 't' and 'f'
2. Using the slice method to slice the first variable of `responseText` to eliminate all the white-spaces in the string and then making further comparison

   ```
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function f() 

   {
   if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 

   {
       result = this.responseText;
       var temp = result.slice(0,1);  
       //This will only select the first char in the result string

       if (temp == "t") 
           document.getElementById('email_pass').innerHTML = 'login successful';

       else
           document.getElementById('email_pass').innerHTML = 'login failed';
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory comment about prepared statements in php and sql [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

But I would try to cast the comparison

```
        if (result == "true")
```

to boolean like so

```
        if (Boolean(result) === true)
```

I admit, my knowledge of ajax and JS is limited but in such cases Ive learned to not trust JS automatic type casting. Note also that I would definately use 3x= if we are casting result to a boolean.

Comment: That's right. However, the issue was not with the data-type as I had checked beforehand the types of both of my variables that were being used i.e. `responseText` and `result`.

Comment: I see, must've missed that part. Good you figured it out! and even better of you to post it for others to see!

Comment: Coding always comes with unspoken duties and responsibilities :)

Comment: Boolean("false") === true

Answer (score -1):

`$result` not getting "true" make sure or double check below:

1. Html element IDs are (email, pass)
2. Database connection work properly,
3. `$qry`: select query related fields have matched with table columns
4. `$result` will get true only if requested email and password exits in database `user_auth` table

I think it may help...good luck

Comment: Since the OP _does_ get `true`, I doubt that any of these points would change anything. The issue is most likely that they have some extra output, probably before or after the echo's.